# ASP MVC Dropdown

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

Please look at my code. I am trying to display some dynamic customers in the dropdown menu. And after selecting a customer button is pressed. Then products owned by the selected customer should be displayed in the textarea. But the problem is that after selecting a customer and pressing the button, nothing is displayed in the text area !. As i am new to ASP MVC can you help me out this problem?

Controller class-------------------->

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
{

    CandidateEntities db;

    public ProductsController()
    {
        db = new CandidateEntities();
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Customers"] = new SelectList(db.Customer.ToList(), "CustomerId", "Firstname");
        return View();
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
    {
        int customerId = int.Parse(form["Customers"]);
        var cust = db.Customer.First(x=>x.CustomerId == customerId);
        var Query =
            from customer in db.Customer
            join prod in db.Products on customerId equals prod.Customer.CustomerId
            select prod;
        ViewData["Products"] = Query.ToString(); 
        return View("Index");
    }



}
```

Index view------------------>

### Index

```
<%using(Html.BeginForm()){ %>   
    <%=Html.DropDownList("Customers", "Seletc one")%>
    <input type="submit" value="Click !" />

    <%=Html.TextArea("Textarea", ViewData["Products"]) %>
<%} %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure your query is returning results?  It seems to be querying for every product for every customer, it might be rewritten something like:

```
from product in db.Prodcuts
where product.Customer.CustomerID = customerId
select product
```

Also, (and it depends on your code), but is calling ToString on a list of Product objects going to return what you want?

Answer (score 1):

```
db.Products.Where(p => p.CustomerId == cust)
```

or

```
db.Customer.Find(cust).Products
```